# SQL query to change value in one column based on value in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do i change the value in one column based on the value in two columns.

```
select Name, acc_type , NewOld
from Account
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld = 0  OR  NewOld = 1
```

If `acc_type= footballer` and `NewOld = 1`, 
The `acc_Type` now becomes `Retired`,

And

if `acc_type= footballer` and `NewOld = 0`,
The `acc_Type` now becomes `New`,

EDIT 1:

Could i do this;

```
UPDATE Account
SET acc_type = Retired
WHERE acc_type = footballer
AND NewOLD = 1
```

EDIT 2:

I tried

```
UPDATE dbo.Account
SET new_AccountType = CASE 
                 WHEN newOld = 1 THEN 'Retired'
                 WHEN newOld = 0 THEN 'New'
              END 
Where new_AccountType = 'Footballer' 
AND newOld IN (0,1)
```

That just changed everything that had an new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Footballer' to 'Retired' ,it did not matter if newOld was 1 or 0?

Why is this?

Comment: Actually whats your question

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server , MySQL , Oracle etc ???

Comment: I want to change the account type to retired , if account type us footballer and newOld is 1.

Comment: Yea that's fine see my update statement, but what RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: I am using sql server 2012

Comment: I have tried this as well OP , and i get the same result as you, Can someone shed some light  on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Case` Statement

```
select Name, 
       case when NewOld = 1 then 'Retired' else 'New' End as acc_type, 
       NewOld
from Account
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld in (0 , 1 )
```

Also your `where` clause will be interpreted as

```
(account_type = 'footballer' AND NewOld = 0)  OR  NewOld = 1
```

But i guess you need this

```
account_type = 'footballer' AND (NewOld = 0  OR  NewOld = 1).
```

Instead of multiple `OR` conditions you can use `IN` opertaor

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Server 2005 and onwards

```
select Name 
     , NewOld
     ,CASE 
          WHEN NewOld = 1 THEN 'Retired'
          WHEN NewOld = 0 THEN 'New'
      END  AS acc_type 
from Account
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld IN (0,1)
```

### SQL Server 2012 and onwards

```
select Name 
     , NewOld
     ,IIF(NewOld = 1 , 'Retired','New') AS acc_type 
from Account
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld IN (0,1)
```

### FOR UPDATE 2005 and onwards

```
UPDATE Account
  SET acc_type  = CASE 
                     WHEN NewOld = 1 THEN 'Retired'
                     WHEN NewOld = 0 THEN 'New'
                  END 
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld IN (0,1)
```

### FOR UPDATE 2012 and onwards

```
UPDATE Account
  SET acc_type  =  IIF(NewOld = 1 , 'Retired','New')
Where account_type = 'footballer'
AND NewOld IN (0,1)
```

Comment: Are you sure he is using `Sql Server`

Comment: @Indian lol good point , I hope he/she is that's what I am going with :)

Comment: Anyway the `IIF` is a better option

Comment: @Indian yes that's if he/she is on 2012 or later versions.